# NSInternalInconsistencyException: RCTBatchedBridge.m line 457 -[RCTBatchedBridge setUpExecutor] crash

Tags: ios, react-native, ios-simulator

My app had a crash of:

> Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
>   -invalidate must be called before -dealloc
>
> Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException 0  CoreFoundation
>   0x1018fff1d (Missing) 1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x100db1bb7
>   (Missing) 2  CoreFoundation                 0x1018ffd9a (Missing) 3 
>   Foundation                     0x1009cf6a7 (Missing) 4  fatberry
>   0x1005a5c66 -[RCTWebSocketExecutor dealloc]
>   (RCTWebSocketExecutor.m:268) 5  libobjc.A.dylib
>   0x100dc628e (Missing) 6  fatberry                       0x100479002
>   -[RCTBatchedBridge setUpExecutor] (RCTBatchedBridge.m:457) 7  fatberry                       0x100474c7e __25-[RCTBatchedBridge start]_block_invoke_2.73
>   (RCTBatchedBridge.m:137) 8  libdispatch.dylib              0x104605af6
>   (Missing) 9  libdispatch.dylib              0x10461faf4 (Missing) 10
>   libdispatch.dylib              0x104608c2e (Missing) 11
>   libdispatch.dylib              0x10461faf4 (Missing) 12
>   libdispatch.dylib              0x10460c464 (Missing) 13
>   libdispatch.dylib              0x10460d2c9 (Missing) 14
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x10498e5a2 (Missing) 15
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x10498e07d (Missing)

Any idea what is the root cause?